# Compilation of openCV on M1 chip doesn't generate necessary file

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, conda, apple-m1

I want to use openCV in conda environment on an M1 chip. Following this https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/, I got pretty far, but don't get the file generated during the compilation step as shown in the example.

Instead of as in example :

```
% mdfind cv2.cpython
/.../opencv-4.5.0/build/lib/python3/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so
...
```

I get only:

```
% mdfind cv2.cpython
/Users/Username/FLASK_MQTT/venv_MQTT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Cmake command I used is:

```
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64 \
  -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 \
  -DWITH_OPENJPEG=OFF \
  -DWITH_IPP=OFF \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/paveltravnicek/opencv_contrib-4.5.0/modules  \
  -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test_openCV/bin/python3/ \
  -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
  -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
  -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
  -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I dont think this output of cmake is quite right, when I see the missing info under Python 3:

```
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      YES (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework -lm -ldl)
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                NO
--     Link libraries:              -framework OpenCL
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test_openCV/bin/python3/ (ver 3.8.6)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       NO (Python3 wrappers can not be generated)
--     install path:                -
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/paveltravnicek/opencv-4.5.0/build
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: While the conda env is activated, make sure that numpy is installed and also add `-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/python3.9/` and `-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.9/site-packages` to your `cmake` command. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, numpy is installed. I also added `-D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ \ ` to the `cmake` command. That solved the address of `numpy:/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/testcv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.5)` under the `Python 3:` info. The rest is unchanged even with suggested commands.

Comment: Silly question, but did you make sure to change the `3.9` from my paths to `3.8` and checked if those are the actual directories on your system?

Comment: Okay, so I got it working. The main issue seems to be that I used `miniforge` instead of `miniforge3`, doing this, the `cmake` stated in tutorial was sufficient. Also, instalation of numpy worked better using `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps` instead of `% pip install --upgrade --no-dependencies --force numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl ` which was causing me an issue about supported version of `numpy` (now using `numpy` version 1.19.5). Thanks for the help!